# Download files directly with apache for authenticated users

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Here is the deal , 
I'm selling some files and they can be downloaded.

So , only the users that have paid for the files can download them.
I want to avoid download via PHP script for many reasons
- The files are large ( some are ~5GB)
- If the download crush , it must start over again.

Is there any way ? Any strategy at all that can help me identify the users that are allowed to download the files , and let apache do the job ( to provide a direct link for download ) instead of using PHP script to stream the file.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about mod auth token?

http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-token/

can be a very good solution - I use a similar strategy but using my own module.

Answer (score 0):

Any URL can be shared, so you're going to have to persist an indication that the file has been downloaded, otherwise one paying visitor can publish the URL and anyone can download it.

Using PHP you can set a flag after the whole file has been transmitted (which roughly indicates a succesful download), so the file can not be downloaded again.

You could also use some kind of authentication, but then again, the credentials can be shared.

Answer (score 0):

One rather easy solution is to use the [virtual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.virtual.php) function. You would auth the user, and then palm off the request to apache. That is *not* using php to stream files.

Answer (score 0):

With some smarts, you could create symlinks to the real file and turn them off after the file has downloaded.

User purchases file: you create a symlink and sent the unique URL to the user. You could then potentially monitor the log file and disable the symlink when the file has been downloaded. Or if you can't access log files, you could send the user to a PHP file that only creates the symlink when the user visits, then turn off the symlink after a certain time (although how can you sure what that time is, I'm not sure).

Not a perfect solution, just throwing an idea around.